# Ios 11.0.3 -Music app - Airplay selection popup

Tags: ios11, appium-ios, airplay

I am not able to find page source or popup handling of Music App using Appium for ios 11.0.3

steps to reproduce

Open music app
Select song
Click on Select airplay device
Challenge:

I am not able capture page source of element of popup
Approach:
tried to capture page source but popup source not listed.

Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odZCf.png)

Comment: How do you search? Do you use appium-desktop?

Comment: with any tool or utility  i am not getting element
tried 
1. Xcode Accessibility Inspector
2. Appium Desktop
3. ios Inspector -External Utility - Browser based.